# php apache_note with mpm_event

Tags: apache-2.2, php, apache-2.4, apache2

I'm wanting to switch to mpm_event to be able to serve a higher rate of requests. My initial testing showed that the server can serve a higher rate of requests when using mpm event.  The server is basically just serving files, but there is a php application running on the server.   I've been using prefork up until now.  The php application uses the apache_note() function to insert some information into the apache logs.  When I run mpm_event, this functionality seems to break (function not found).  Is mpm_event compatible with apache_note(), or should I use some other method to insert data into the logs?

Answer (score 2):

Certain functions, like [`apache_note()`](https://secure.php.net/apache_note), are only available when PHP runs as an Apache module. Using this, or anything specific to mod_php, is usually a bad idea due to lock-in. Consider using a standard function like [`trigger_error()`](https://secure.php.net/trigger_error) instead. It was specifically designed for what you want to do, unlike `apache_note()`.

Comment: Is there a function that can be used to insert general information into the logs?  My use case is that I grab the username from the request and add it into the log.

Comment: I think maybe just using headers would accomplish the same task?

Comment: Apache has a very rich log format. Depending on the design of your application, it may be able to log your desired data alone without any help from PHP.

Comment: Issue is that I decrypt a cookie to pull the userid out.  This is done with PHP and then added to the logs.

Comment: @yossarian2004 You probably should be keeping your own logs. Sticking this stuff in the Apache log is kind of messy.